# Filenames containing diacritics are not displayed properly using Javascript in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file

So, after having not programmed for 23 years, I decided to start learning Javascript.
I am trying to write a program to read through my music files and create a HTML page based on the files found in a specific directory.

It goes well until I hit filenames containing diacritics in it (like é, ü, ø etc).

For Example: André Hazes turns into : AndrÃ© Hazes

For Example: Andrea Bocelli & Sarah Brightman - Time to Say Goodbye [Con Te Partirò] (single) turn into Andrea Bocelli & Sarah Brightman - Time to Say Goodbye [Con Te PartiroÌ€] (single)

The link I have created doesn't work anymore

The command I use to create the HTML statement is:

```
<td><a href="${item.vDir}/${item.vFilename}">${item.vFilename}</a></td>
```

This is the code I use to read the files from the filesystem. I work on a Mac, OS Catalina, so basically an Unix variant.

```
// List all files in a directory in Node.js recursively in a synchronous fashion
var ReadDirFiles = function(pdir, pfilelist) {
  files = vFileSystem.readdirSync(pdir,"utf-8");
  filelist = pfilelist;
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    if (vFileSystem.statSync(pdir + '/' + file).isDirectory()) {
      filelist = ReadDirFiles(pdir + '/' + file, filelist);
    }
    else {
      vstats = vFileSystem.statSync(pdir + '/' + file);
      // debug info
      // console.log(vstats);
      filelist.push({vFilename: file, vDir: pdir, vBirthtime: formatDate(vstats.birthtime), vSize: vstats.size});
    }
  });
  return filelist;
};
```

This is the statement I use to write the output to disk and it turns out the problem is in the write statement:

```
fs.writeFileSync(buildPathHtml.buildPathHtml(), html);
```

When the output is written back to disk, the conversion of the diacritics happens.

Anyone knows the trick how to work diacritics?

Comment: Maybe your file system isn't utf8 based. Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am working on Mac, so a Unix variant. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/is-mac-os-x-unix

Answer (score 0):

Try using encoding and decoding functions in your script. There are many functions doing this in Javascript, just use what you need. For a complete encoding/decoding you can use (or only copy & paste) into your script the code suggested in https://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode/. There is a little encoding Javascript library doing the job ([encoder.js](https://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js)).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that is not the solution. The problems occurs at the moment of writing the file to the OS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file system isn't utf8 based. I read somewhere it's `Western` for Mac.